# Async Task for Login HttpPost Android

Tags: android, authentication, android-asynctask

I was following a youtube guide for a Log-In in android. I have reached thus far and I believe that the youtube guide relies on earlier SDKs to get it to work. For ICS and newer versions, I have read that I need to use Async (I was getting the NetworkOnMainThreadException). I have been working 2 days trying to figure out how to implement this.

This is stuck at the Loading terminal until the app stops working. Is it because I have too much inside the RunInBackground()?

How would I go about getting my methods to work within a proper amount of time.

I appreciate anyones help on this. BTW, I have read a lot of documents that say to implement Async Task, but my question is more towards how would I do this?

**also the back-end: app sends info the index.php on a wamp server and then the php talks to the database.

```
package com.sokies.my_team;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etUser, etPass;
    Button bLogin;

    //Create string variables that will have the input assigned to them
    String username, password;

    //Create a HTTPClient as the form container
    HttpClient httpclient;

    //Use HTTP POST method
    HttpPost httppost;

    //Create an array list for the input data to be sent
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    //Create a HTTP Response and HTTP Entity
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialise();

    }



    private void initialise() {
        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
        //Now to set an onClickListener
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)  {
        // This is where we will be working now

        new MyAsyncTask().execute();

    }//END onClick()

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }//END convertStreamToString()



    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //Create new default HTTPClient
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Create new HTTP POST with URL to php file as parameter
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/myteamapp/index.php"); 

            //Assign input text to strings
            username = etUser.getText().toString();
            password = etPass.getText().toString();



            //Next block of code needs to be surrounded by try/catch block for it to work
            try {
                //Create new Array List
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                //place them in an array list
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "username"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "password"));

                //Add array list to http post
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                //assign executed form container to response
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //response from the PHP file

                //check status code, need to check status code 200
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){

                    //assign response entity to http entity
                    entity = response.getEntity();

                    //check if entity is not null
                    if(entity != null){


                        //Create new input stream with received data assigned
                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                        //Create new JSON Object. assign converted data as parameter.
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                        //assign json responses to local strings
                        String retUser = jsonResponse.getString("user");//mySQL table field
                        String retPass = jsonResponse.getString("pass");

                        //Validate login
                        if(username.equals(retUser)&& password.equals(retPass)){ //Check whether 'retUser' and 'retPass' matches username/password 

                            //Display a Toast saying login was a success
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        } else {
                            //Display a Toast saying it failed.

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }


                }


            } catch(Exception e){

               // e.printStackTrace();
                //Display toast when there is a connection error
                //Change message to something more friendly
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               return null;
            }



            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform an operation with UI (in your case it's showing `Toast`) from background thread, which is forbidden in android. Try to return a value (f.e., 1 for success and 0 for fail) in `doInBackground` method and process it in `onPostExecute`, which is called on UI thread.

In other words, always perform operations with user interface on main thread: in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods before and after running background task, respectfully.

Comment: I see what you are saying, thanks for that. Whenever I run it in the emulator, it gets stuck at "Loading... Loading Data section". It does not seem to progress any farther. 
* I removed Toasts from the code

Comment: @Sokies Have you tried to debug your code? Just put breakpoint in the beginning of `doInBackground` method and follow the code running step by step. It seems to me that the only thing that can stop progress in your case is sending http request and receiving response. I'm not sure how does it work when request time out is not set (like in your case), so try to set timeout for your request:

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), timeoutInMiliseconds);

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I believe my error was the Toast action I was trying to perform and thus why I was getting stuck. It took a simple removal of Toast and a change to "localhost" in the php location to get it to work. :)